# How to sum same region's value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows = 20
np.random.seed(12345)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(10, 6))
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)
```

I made a DataFrame code;

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3)),
                 index=[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']],
                 columns=[['ps', 'ys','cw'],
                          ])
frame.columns.names = ['region']
```

And the result is below;

```
region  ps      ys      cw
a       0       1       2
a       3       4       5
b       6       7       8
b       9       10      11
c       12      13      14
```

I want to find the number of times each person has visited each area.
So I made a code.

```
def calling(index,columns):
    frame.loc('index')
    c = frame.sum(columns)
    print(index, c)
```

In my purpose, the output is (a,7) when I write calling(a,cw).
Also, calling('c','ys') makes (c,13), and calling('b','ps') figures out (b,15).
But the results didn't come out. How should I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subset your dataframe in the function, first by index then column:

```
def calling(index,column):
    c = frame.loc[index][[column]].sum()[0]
    print(index, c)
```

And you need to provide the columns as a string not a variable:

```
calling('a','cw')
a 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to group the dataframe by its index, so you can use the following:

```py
frame.groupby(frame.index).sum()
```